# Regarding ndarray creation in julia: Stacking in extra dimension

Tags: python, numpy, julia

I would like to convert the following python code into julia:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.random.random([4,5,6])
y = np.array([[x,  x,  x  ],
              [2*x,3*x,4*x]])
print(y.shape)
-> (2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
```

In julia, the analogous syntax seems to me is

```
x = rand(4,5,6) 
y = [x x x; 2x 3x 4x]
println(size(y))
-> (8, 15, 6)
```

These results are different. Can you tell me how to do it?

Comment: Look up the `cat` function to concatenate along arbitrary dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

Using random numbers and multipliers obscures the details which you seek. Let's do consecutive numbering and try to get Python and Julia to display alike:

```
python>>>>>> z = np.reshape(np.array(range(1,121)), [4, 5, 6])
>>> z
array([[[  1,   2,   3,   4,   5,   6],
        [  7,   8,   9,  10,  11,  12],
        [ 13,  14,  15,  16,  17,  18],
        [ 19,  20,  21,  22,  23,  24],
        [ 25,  26,  27,  28,  29,  30]],

       [[ 31,  32,  33,  34,  35,  36],
        [ 37,  38,  39,  40,  41,  42],
        [ 49,  50,  51,  52,  53,  54],
        [ 55,  56,  57,  58,  59,  60]],

       [[ 61,  62,  63,  64,  65,  66],
        [ 67,  68,  69,  70,  71,  72],
        [ 73,  74,  75,  76,  77,  78],
        [ 79,  80,  81,  82,  83,  84],
        [ 85,  86,  87,  88,  89,  90]],

       [[ 91,  92,  93,  94,  95,  96],
        [ 97,  98,  99, 100, 101, 102],
        [103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108],
        [109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114],
        [115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120]]])

julia>z = reshape(1:120, 6, 5, 4)
6×5×4 reshape(::UnitRange{Int64}, 6, 5, 4) with eltype Int64:
[:, :, 1] =
 1   7  13  19  25
 2   8  14  20  26
 3   9  15  21  27
 4  10  16  22  28
 5  11  17  23  29
 6  12  18  24  30

[:, :, 2] =
 31  37  43  49  55
 32  38  44  50  56
 33  39  45  51  57
 34  40  46  52  58
 35  41  47  53  59
 36  42  48  54  60

[:, :, 3] =
 61  67  73  79  85
 62  68  74  80  86
 63  69  75  81  87
 64  70  76  82  88
 65  71  77  83  89
 66  72  78  84  90

[:, :, 4] =
 91   97  103  109  115
 92   98  104  110  116
 93   99  105  111  117
 94  100  106  112  118
 95  101  107  113  119
 96  102  108  114  120
```

So, if you want things to print similarly on the screen, you need to swap first and last dimension sizes (reverse the order of dimensions) on the arrays between Julia and Python. In addition, since Julia concatenates the arrays when you put them in the same brackets, but Python just nests its arrays in greater depth, you need to use  np.reshape on Python or reshape on Julia to change the arrays to the shape you want. I suggest you check the resulting arrays on a consecutive set of integers to be sure they print alike before going back to your random floating point numbers. Remember that the indexing order is different when you access elements, too. Consider

```
>>> zzz = np.array([[z,z,z], [z,z,z]]) # python

> zzz = reshape([z z z; z z z], 6, 5, 4, 3, 2) # julia
```