# Julia: Adding element-wise operations on certain dimensions using EllipsisNotation

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, julia

As the last time, I would like to translate the following python code into julia

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import pi as π
A = np.random.random([3,4,5,6]) # arbitrary dimensions
σ = np.array([[π, -π],
              [π,  1]])
B = A[...,1:2,1:2] + σ
```

My approach up to now does not work

```
using EllipsisNotation
A = rand(3,4,5,6)
σ = [π  -π;
     π   1]
B = A[..,1:2,1:2] + σ
```

and I dot see an other way than looping through the other dimensions. Do you see how it can be done?

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you are trying to do things that are extremely peculiar to numpy, and are deeply tied to a row-oriented way of thinking. Numpy, apparently, is prepending dimensions to arrays in a way that is hard to comprehend, and seem quite unnatural (how can adding a (3,4,1,1) array with a (2,2) array work?! The dimensions don't match!). The same thing applies to your previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57694631/regarding-ndarray-creation-in-julia-stacking-in-extra-dimension).

Shifting dimensions outwards seems almost bizarre to me. Julia, perhaps because it's column major, doesn't work like that.

Some pieces of advice

- You have to turn your thinking around, from row-major to column major.
- When attempting broadcasting you must use dotted operators: `A .+ σ`.
- Indexing is 1-based and inclusive, instead of `A[1:2]` use `A[2:2]` or just `A[2]`.

That being said, you can achieve the same result in Julia by doing this (**edit:** I made a mistake with 1- vs 0-based indexing, fixed now):

```
B = A[.., 2, 2] .+ reshape(σ, (1, 1, size(σ)...))
```

BTW: I had *no* idea you can use unicode identifiers in Python!! Very cool.